# Shoe not moving with Leg when posing (armature)

Tags: rigging, armature, rigify

Im fairly new to blender. I have made a character with a pair of shoes.
I created a rig, sellected all (the whole character with shoes) then Alt + LMB to select the rig the rig and finally Ctrl + P.

Now when i bend the legs, the shoes stay on the ground.

I have tried joining the shoe with the leg before attaching them to the rig but then they both dont move at all when i pose the rig. Am i doing anything wrong?

Comment: select armature -> automatic weights

Comment: I have already done that. The shoes stay on the ground.

Comment: do the process separately for shoe and the body

Answer (score 0):

You probably didn't weight paint the shoes.

First, name your feet bones something that you can remember. Then, parent the shoes to the bones again. Go into the properties panel > Object data (the green triangle) and then in the vertex groups look for your foot bone name. Select that, go into weight paint mode, and paint the shoe. That should cause your shoe to move.

Hope this works